# Use $.post methods returned function(data) value to variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**Dear Coders!**

The purpose of my code:

Get URL of files listed in specific folder, then assign them to an Array in javascript.

How I'm imagining it:
JavaScript function in `test.php` uses `$.post()` method to send a value to `getURL.php` file. After this, `getURL.php` uses this value to get specific file URLs in a specific folder. I'm getting the result(s) in the `$.post()` methods `function(data)` parameter. After this, the resulted value of the "data" is (/would be used) in JavaScript.

The problem:
Inside the `$.post()` methods function: `function(data,status) I'm satisfied with the result of the returned value of the data parameter; the PROBLEM is that I can't assign it's value outside this function:`function (data,status)`.

TEST.php

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgPath; // <--He is who should get the value of "data"
    function getTargetUrl(szolg){
        $.post(
            "getURL.php",
            { x: szolg },
            function(data,status){
                alert("in function: " + data + " status: " + status);
                imgPath=data;
                alert (imgPath);
            }
        );
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var a="szolg5"; //it will be "user defined", used in getURL.php
        getTargetUrl(a);
        alert(imgPath);
    });
</script>
```

getURL.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["x"])){
    $queryGlob='img/'.$_POST["x"].'/batch/*.jpg';
    foreach (glob($queryGlob) as $filename) {
        $imgFiles=json_encode($filename);
        $imgFiles=str_replace('\/','/',$imgFiles);
        echo $imgFiles;
    }
    //$data = str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode(glob('img/'.$_POST["x"].'/batch/*.jpg')));
}
else{
    $imgFiles="FAIL";
    echo $imgFiles;
}
?>
```

Note: for testing I'm using Google Chrome.

So that's all I guess, hope someone can give me a solution and possible explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `post` call is **asynchronous**, so in your code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a="szolg5"; //it will be "user defined", used in getURL.php
    getTargetUrl(a);
    alert(imgPath);
});
```

...the `alert` occurs **before** the `post` call has completed, and so shows the old value of `imgPath`. What you want to do is pass a function into `getTargetUrl` that it will call when the `post` completes, and put the subsequent code in there.

Something like this:

```
var imgPath; // <--He is who should get the value of "data"
function getTargetUrl(szolg, callback){
    $.post(
        "getURL.php",
        { x: szolg },
        function(data,status){
            alert("in function: " + data + " status: " + status);
            imgPath=data;
            callback();
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a="szolg5"; //it will be "user defined", used in getURL.php
    getTargetUrl(a, function() {
        alert(imgPath);
    });
});
```

And you can do away with the global variable entirely by doing what `post` does and passing the data back as an argument:

```
function getTargetUrl(szolg, callback){
    $.post(
        "getURL.php",
        { x: szolg },
        function(data,status){
            alert("in function: " + data + " status: " + status);
            callback(data);
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a="szolg5"; //it will be "user defined", used in getURL.php
    getTargetUrl(a, function(path) {
        alert(path);
    });
});
```

Comment: This soloution ended up being the best for me. Thank You all for Your help!

Answer (score 0):

No, AJAX is asynchronous meaning that the `$.post` method will return immediately. If you want to use the results of an AJAX call, the only safe place to do so is inside the success callback. Do not attempt to assign the result to global variables.

So you should put the alert **inside** the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others the reason for this behavior is the asynchronous nature of ajax requests.

My solution will to return the ajax promise request from `getTargetUrl` and use it to register callback methods

```
function getTargetUrl(szolg){
    return $.post(
        "getURL.php",
        { x: szolg },
        function(data,status){
            alert("in function: " + data + " status: " + status);
            alert (data);
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a="szolg5"; //it will be "user defined", used in getURL.php
    getTargetUrl(a).done(function(data){
        alert('from callback' + data);
    });
});
```